# "Time" as continuous, ordinal, or nominal in this REML design?

Tags: time-series, ordinal-data, continuous-data, categorical-data, reml

I've assayed two treatment groups at three time points. The time points are "days post inoculation" (specifically, 0, 20 and 40 days), so the interval between the measure is meaningful.

I've modelled my data three ways, all REML.

1) With "time" as continuous, "treatment" and "time" are significant, but there's no interaction.

2) With "time" as ordinal, the main effect "treatment" is not significant, but "time" and the interaction are.

3) And with "time" as nominal, both main effects and the interaction are significant.

When I post-hoc test (LS means contrast) "treatment" at different "times" (continuous) I do see that at time 0 there's no difference between treatments, but at time points 20 and 40 there are differences. But in order to run those contrasts I have to leave in the (non-significant) interaction.

How is that my post-hoc tests show these differences at the different time points, yet the interaction is non-significant?

Another question: Is it wrong to model time as nominal or ordinal?

Comment: Did you allow for a random effect of time in your models? Just curious. What are the p values for each of the effects referenced? Also what do you mean by time as "ordinal" 0,1,2? An interaction term created with such a variable should have the same properties as one where time is measured as 0, 20, 40 (as one is just a linear transformation of the other). Sorry for all of the questions, just trying to rule out possible explanations.

Comment: Yes, the random effect is the replicate - measured 3 times. I guess when "time" is "ordinal" it doesn't matter whether it's 0, 20, 40, or 0,1,2, or 0,1,10000 as the order would matter, not the value, right? (just for clarity, "ordinal" is one of the data categories in JMP. One of the three: Nominal, ordinal, and continuous). I'll dig out the p values. Off the top of my head: Time as continuous: Both main effects p<0.001, interaction =0.13x. Time as nominal: both main effects p<0.001, interaction p = 0.008. Time as ordinal: "treatment" p = 0.4xx, time and interaction <0.001.

Comment: What you have is actually a miniature growth model here. I am not familiar with JMP and its defaults (or how it would treat an ordinal predictor differently from a continuous one). I would select between time as continuous or time as categorical. The former will force you to examine linear change  (i.e., the average slope across all three time points). The latter will let you compare means at each time point for each group without imposing a linear structure on change. Note that centering decisions for time (i.e., what 0 represents) will affect your interpretation of the treatment effect.